# What should be Output shape of keras model layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

i am bit confused about the output shape of keras layer. I have created a sample keras model and also displayed its summary.

```
numberOfLSTMcells=1
n_timesteps_in=129
n_features=61
inp =Input(shape=(n_timesteps_in, n_features))
lstm= LSTM(numberOfLSTMcells,return_sequences=True, return_state=False) (inp)
fc=Dense(64,activation='relu',name='hidden_layer')(lstm)
out=Dense(1,activation='sigmoid',name='last_layer')(fc)
model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=out)
```

Summary of model

```
Model: "model_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_3 (InputLayer)         [(None, 129, 61)]         0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_2 (LSTM)                (None, 129, 1)            252       
_________________________________________________________________
hidden_layer (Dense)         (None, 129, 64)           128       
_________________________________________________________________
last_layer (Dense)           (None, 129, 1)            65        
=================================================================
Total params: 445
Trainable params: 445
Non-trainable params: 0
```

What i think the shape of last layer should be `(None,64,1)`. Becuase hidden_layers has 64 neurons which goes as input to last_layer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you set the parameter `return_sequences` to `True` in the `LSTM` layer, you are getting a sequence with the same number of time steps as your input and an output space of 1 for each timestep, hence the shape `(None, 129, 1)`. Afterwards, you apply a `Dense` layer to this tensor, but this layer is always applied to the last dimension of a tensor, which in your case is 1 and not 129. Therefore you get the output `(None, 129, 64)`. Then, you use a final output layer, which is also applied to the last dimension of your tensor resulting in output with the shape `(None, 129, 1)`. The Tensorflow [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dense) also explain this behavior:

> If the input to the layer has a rank greater than 2, then Dense computes the dot product between the inputs and the kernel along the **last** axis of the inputs and axis 0 of the kernel (using tf.tensordot).

You can set `return_sequences` to `False` if you want to work with a 2D output `(batch_size, features)` instead of 3D `(batch_size, time_steps, features)`, or you can use the `Flatten` layer.