# ValueError: Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1 for '{{node binary_crossentropy/weighted_loss/Squeeze}}

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to fit a LSTM-model to my data with a Masking Layer in front and I get this error:

`ValueError: Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 4 for '{{node binary_crossentropy/weighted_loss/Squeeze}} = Squeeze[T=DT_FLOAT, squeeze_dims=[-1]](Cast)' with input shapes: [128,4].`

This is my code:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, BatchNormalization, Masking
from tensorflow.keras.losses import BinaryCrossentropy
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Nadam
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    # define stub data
    samples, timesteps, features = 128, 4, 99
    X = np.random.rand(samples, timesteps, features)
    Y = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(samples))
    
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Masking(mask_value=0., input_shape=(None, 99)))
    model.add(LSTM(100, return_sequences=True))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    optimizer = Nadam(learning_rate=0.0001)
    loss = BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=False)
    model.compile(loss=loss, optimizer=optimizer)

    # train model
    model.fit(
        X,
        Y,
        batch_size=128)
```

I see from [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49083984/valueerror-can-not-squeeze-dim1-expected-a-dimension-of-1-got-3-for-sparse), that I can't use one-hot encoded labels, but my labels are not one-hot encoded.
Also, when I remove the masking layer, training works.

From my understanding one sample consists of 4 timesteps with 99 features here. The shape of X is therefore `(128,4,99)`
Therefore, I only have to provide one label for each sample, the shape of Y therefore being `(128,)`

But it seems like the dimensions of X and or Y are not correct, as tensorflow wants to change its dimensions?
I have tried providing a label per timestep of each sample (`Y = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(samples, timesteps))`, with the same result.

Why does adding the masking layer introduce this error? And how can I keep the masking layer without getting the error?

System Information:

- Python version: 3.9.5
- Tensorflow version: 2.5.0
- OS: Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the problem is the `Masking` layer. Since you set the parameter `return_sequences` to `True` in the `LSTM` layer, you are getting a sequence with the same number of time steps as your input and an output space of 100 for each timestep, hence the shape `(128, 4, 100)`, where 128 is the batch size. Afterwards, you apply a `BatchNormalization` layer and finally a `Dense` layer resulting in the shape `(128, 4, 1)`. The problem is your labels have a 2D shape `(128, 1)` and your model has a 3D output due to the `return_sequences` parameter. So, simply setting this parameter to `False` should solve your problem. See also this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70087143/what-should-be-output-shape-of-keras-model-layers/70088019#70088019).

Here is a working example:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, BatchNormalization, Masking
from tensorflow.keras.losses import BinaryCrossentropy
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Nadam
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    # define stub data
    samples, timesteps, features = 128, 4, 99
    X = np.random.rand(samples, timesteps, features)
    Y = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(samples))
    
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Masking(mask_value=0., input_shape=(None, 99)))
    model.add(LSTM(100, return_sequences=False))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    optimizer = Nadam(learning_rate=0.0001)
    loss = BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=False)
    model.compile(loss=loss, optimizer=optimizer)

    # train model
    model.fit(
        X,
        Y,
        batch_size=128)
```